# C++ Constructors of template based derived class & variable arguments

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, ellipsis

Developing in c++ after a long time, so please bear with my ignorance on the language.. 
In my design I have derived class, for which the base class is passed using templates.

```
template <class DeviceType, class SwitchType> class Controller : public SwitchType
{
public:
/* Constructor */
Controller(byte ID, byte NumberOfDevices, int size, int data[]) : SwitchType(size, data) 
   {
   }
};
```

I am using this as follows:

```
Controller <ValueDriven, Eth_Driver> ctn(1, 2, 3, new int[3]{2, 3, 8});
```

Is it possible to use ellipsis here? so that end result would like this ..

```
Controller<ValueDriven, Eth_Driver> ctn(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 8);
```

I tried ellipses, but couldnt find a way to pass ellipse from Controller to SwitchType.

Note* Using this for arduino platform. So staying away from std::lib

Comment: I've felt some memory being leaked somewhere...

Comment: Yes a leak exists if the data is not deleted.

Comment: Why are you calling `new` in the first place? You have all the information at compile-time.

Comment: How is the `SwitchType` constructed? Do you need to store these values somewhere, or are they immediately processed in the constructor?

Comment: Each Switch types use data to initialize some values and then delete data in the end. I am thinking .. different SwitchTypes must have similar constructors, and then user can choose while instantiating which kind of switch is associated with this controller.
*Regarding new, not aware if there is another way to pass a array of constants.

Comment: @RB1987 Are you still working on this? If so, please provide an example of a SwitchType constructor, so I can have a look at how these values are being used. PS. I would have responded faster if you had addressed the comment at me using "@username". Use this to your advantage!

Answer (score 5):

You could make your constructor into a [variadic template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template):

```
//take any number of args
template <typename... Args>
Controller(byte ID, byte NumberOfDevices, int size, Args&&... data)
    : SwitchType(size,std::forward<Args>(data)...)
{
}
```

Now you can call the constructor like this:

```
Controller<ValueDriven, Eth_Driver> ctn(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 8);
//                                            ^ size
//                                               ^^^^^^^ forwarded
```

Comment: Nice one, though you'd have the problem of storing these values somewhere, and he'd probably have to do without `std::forward`, or implement it himself.

Answer (score 0):

@TartanLlama above did not work for me in visual studio 13 (C++ or arduino dev environment).

After some trials found this to work.

```
class test1
{
public:
    test1(int argc, ...)
    {

        printf("Size: %d\n", argc);
        va_list list;
        va_start(list, argc);
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        {
            printf("Values: %d \n", va_arg(list, int));
        }
        va_end(list);
    }
};

class test2 : public test1
{
public:

    template<typename... Values> test2(int val, int argc, Values... data) : test1(argc, data...)
    {
        printf("\n\nSize @Derived: %d\n", argc);
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, argc);
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        {
            printf("Values @Derived: %d\n", va_arg(args, int));
        }
        va_end(args);
    }
};

void setup()
{

    test2(2090, 3, 30, 40, 50);
}

void loop()
{

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setup();
    while (1) 
    {
        loop();
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```